# The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine. in win10

Tags: c#

hello guys  my info system:

win10 64bit

office 2013 64bit

visual stadio 2013

when i want create a conection (access .accdb) visual stadio Error this (The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine. ) please help me , i try fix this with other Questions but I got confused

there is many sloution for the many ways . i want sloution for my info (office201364bit,win10,visual stadio 2013)

Comment: Explain the "but I got confused" part of your question.